# How can I get the name of the user that published post in a public Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-group, facebook-feed

I already have the following permissions: 'groups_access_member_info', 'Groups API', 'pages_messaging'.
My direction was 'user_posts' permission that rejected and I don't know what to fix in submitting this request. I also thought about via and from.
I would be really happy to help..
Thanks!

Comment: `from` is the user (or other entity) that published a post, yes. Don’t expect to see data in there for normal users though, before you did not submit your app for review. You’ll have to test this with accounts that have a role in your app, only for those it should work in dev mode.

Comment: What do "accounts that have a role in your app" mean? After all, the post was posted in a group (which already added my app) and I can't add a group to my role ... If I didn't understand you correctly I'd love to have a little more detailed explanation :)

Comment: Role in the app means any account that is an admin, developer or tester of the app. The post in the group feed must have been made by any of those.